# NSubstitute - TestFixture 1 causes AmbiguousArgumentsException in TestFixture 2

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute

I am writing C# unit tests using NUnit and NSubstitute. I am testing a class which will attempt to retrieve objects from a config provider implementing the following interface:

```
public interface IConfigProvider<T> {
    T GetConfig(int id);
    T GetConfig(string id);
}
```

The class being tested only uses the int version of `GetConfig` so in the SetUpFixture I do the following to set up a mocked config provider that will always return the same dummy object:

```
IConfigProvider<ConfigType> configProvider = Substitute.For<IConfigProvider<ConfigType>>();
configProvider.GetConfig(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns<ConfigType>(new ConfigType(/* args */);
```

This runs absolutely fine if that TestFixture is the only one being run. However, in a different TestFixture in the same assembly, I check for received calls like this:

```
connection.Received(1).SetCallbacks(Arg.Any<Action<Message>>(), Arg.Any<Action<long>>(), Arg.Any<Action<long, Exception>>());
```

If these `Received` tests run before the config provider tests, then the config tests fail in the SetUpFixture with an AmbiguousArgumentsException:

```
Here.Be.Namespace.ProfileManagerTests+Setup (TestFixtureSetUp):
SetUp : NSubstitute.Exceptions.AmbiguousArgumentsException : Cannot determine argument specifications to use.
Please use specifications for all arguments of the same type.
at NSubstitute.Core.Arguments.NonParamsArgumentSpecificationFactory.Create(Object argument, IParameterInfo parameterInfo, ISuppliedArgumentSpecifications suppliedArgumentSpecifications)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__7`2.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at NSubstitute.Core.Arguments.MixedArgumentSpecificationsFactory.Create(IList`1 argumentSpecs, Object[] arguments, IParameterInfo[] parameterInfos)
at NSubstitute.Core.Arguments.ArgumentSpecificationsFactory.Create(IList`1 argumentSpecs, Object[] arguments, IParameterInfo[] parameterInfos, MatchArgs matchArgs)
at NSubstitute.Core.CallSpecificationFactory.CreateFrom(ICall call, MatchArgs matchArgs)
at NSubstitute.Routing.Handlers.RecordCallSpecificationHandler.Handle(ICall call)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at NSubstitute.Routing.Route.Handle(ICall call)
at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleForwardingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
at Castle.Proxies.IConfigProvider`1Proxy.GetConfig(Int32 id)
at Here.Be.Namespace.ProfileManagerTests.Setup.DoSetup()
```

What's really confusing me is that I can observe this effect even between test runs - if I use the NUnit GUI to run the `Received` tests alone, and then run the config tests alone, the config tests will fail. If I then immediately run the config tests again, they will pass.

Things I've tried:

- Adding `configProvider.GetConfig(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns...` as well, in case the overloading was the problem.
- I've read the [NSubstitute docs on argument matching](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/), but I can't find a solution there. If it is a case of having to supply argument matchers for both the int and string versions of the method, I can't work out how to do that.

As it happens, the tests I'm using will only ever call the `GetConfig` method with values of 0 or 1, so I can just provide `Returns` specifications for those two values and not use matching at all, but I want to understand how to fix this more generally.

Comment: Are you using any arg matchers in the `new ConfigType(/* args */)` code?

Comment: No, I have an enum instance, a string, and an empty List<int> - just placeholder arguments to create a just-good-enough object for the receiver to accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ambiguous arguments is when NSubstitute compares the arguments to the call it is currently working with, to the stack of "argument matchers" it has (each time `Arg.Blah` is called, an the argument matcher is added to that stack), and it is unable to resolve which argument goes where.

Normally this is caused by having a call like `blah(null, null)`, with a single argument matcher queued up, but it can also be caused by the stack getting out-of-sync due to an arg matcher being used outside of call configuration, or as an argument to a non-virtual method.

Version 1.8.0 (released after your question) includes slightly improved detection of the latter case, so that may be worth trying.

Other than that, I've had this problem a few times and have used the following (painful) approach.

- run the test in isolation and ensure it passes
- work out what test runs immediately proceeding (can usually guess, but test logs can help here), and run just those two tests. Confirm it fails.
- Look for any calls to `Arg.xyz` that could queue up an argument matcher in either test. Make sure it is used as part of a call configuration. Sometimes working out which call is problematic can be done by commenting out lines or replacing arg matchers with other values.
- Make sure there are no calls to non-virtual methods that are confusing NSubstitute.

Sometimes the problem may be due to a previous fixture, so you may need to workout the previous fixture and explore there as well. :(

Comment: "Make sure there are no calls to non-virtual methods that are confusing NSubstitute."  
That was the problem, I made various methods of `Connection` virtual, but `SetCallbacks` wasn't one of them. It is now, and the second fixture is now working fine :)

Answer (score 3):

I [had similar errors](https://mfreidge.wordpress.com/2016/05/07/nsubstitute-ambiguousargumentsexception-cannot-determine-argument-specifications-to-use/) that started when I switched Microsoft test runner to `VSTest.Console` (they did not happened when running under `MSTest.exe`).

As it was advised in [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26856185/52277), the errors were caused by calls to non-substituted methods with `Arg.*` parameters. `Arg.Any` were passed to actual code methods, that where called without `Returns` or `Received` relevant methods.

To scan my test library for such issues I used search with regular expression to find rows with `Arg.` but not `Arg.` following by `Returns` or preceded by `Received`

```
(?=^.*Arg.*$)(?=^((?!Arg.*\.Returns).)*$)^((?!\.Received\(.*Arg.).)*$
```

It's not bullet proof filter (e.g it doesn't exclude multi-line statements), but it helps to reduce number of calls to check.

Comment: Thank you Michael, this helps.  

A minor improvement I made was to add a period after the first Arg, like this `(?=^.*Arg\..*$)(?=^((?!Arg.*\.Returns).)*$)^((?!\.Received\(.*Arg.).)*$`.  

I also instructed Visual Studio's find tool to "Match case".

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of my tests worked. Not a great answer, but worked - do try!

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex I ended up using (in Rider, in my case, but it's a standard .Net regex). It handles multi-line statements pretty well. I did have some false negatives show up that had `Returns()` calls appended, but it was less than 1 percent of the total number of usages.

It does not handle `When()`/`Do()` or the `WithAnyArgs` variants, but those were by far the minority of the usages in my particular codebase.

`^(?!\s*\.)[\w\s_\.]+\.(?!DidNotReceive\(\)\s*)(?!Received\(\d*\)\s*)[\w_]+\((((Arg.Any<.*?>\(\))|(Arg.Is(<.*?>)?\(.*\)))[,\s]*)+\)(?!\s*\.Return)(?!\s*?\.Throw)`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem of finding mis-used `Arg` specs using an assembly level attribute, that verifies that before and after a test there are no queued up argument specs pending. It's for NUnit, but the concept should generalize to other unit test frameworks.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; 
using Tests;
using NSubstitute; // 4.2.2
using NSubstitute.Core;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Interfaces;

// apply this ITestAction to all tests in the assembly
[assembly: VerifyNSubstituteUsage]

namespace Tests;

/// <summary>
/// This attribute can help if you experience <see cref="NSubstitute.Exceptions.AmbiguousArgumentsException"/>s.
/// It will ensure that no NSubstitute argument specifications are left in the queue, before or after a test.
/// This will happen if you pass <c>Arg.Any&lt;T&gt;()</c> (or other argument spec)
/// to an instance that is not generated with <see cref="Substitute"/><c>.</c><see cref="Substitute.For{T}"/>
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The <see cref="ITestAction.BeforeTest"/> and <see cref="ITestAction.AfterTest"/> will be run for every test and test fixture
/// </remarks>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class VerifyNSubstituteUsageAttribute : Attribute, ITestAction
{
    public ActionTargets Targets => ActionTargets.Suite | ActionTargets.Test;
    public void BeforeTest(ITest test) => AssertNoQueuedArgumentSpecifications(test);
    public void AfterTest(ITest test) => AssertNoQueuedArgumentSpecifications(test);

    private static void AssertNoQueuedArgumentSpecifications(ITest test, [CallerMemberName] string member = null)
    {
        var specs = SubstitutionContext.Current.ThreadContext.DequeueAllArgumentSpecifications();
        if (specs.Count == 0) return;

        var message = $"{member}: Unused queued argument specifications: '{string.Join("', '", specs)}'.\n" +
                      $"Please check {test.FullName} test for usage of Arg.Is(...) or Arg.Any<T>() " +
                      $"with an instance not generated by Substitute.For<T>(...) ";

        Assert.Fail(message);
    }
}
```